# how to improve index on this table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
  GA,
  mkt_cd,
  mkt_name 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    SUM(GA) AS GA,
    sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd,
    sales_data_mkt.mkt_name 
  FROM
    sales_data_mkt 
  WHERE sales_data_mkt.country_cd = 'USA' 
    AND activity_dt BETWEEN '2015-08-01' 
    AND '2015-08-31' 
    AND sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd 
  ORDER BY (SUM(GA)) DESC) AS innerQuery 
WHERE GA > 0 
LIMIT 10
```

I have an index 
`country_cd, activity_dt, mkt_cd`

The explain statement returns this:

`Key used:` **country_cd, activity_dt, mkt_cd**

`key_len:` **12**
`ref:` **const**

`rows:` **909518**

`Extra:` **Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; using filesort**

This query takes about 5 secs to return on a table with 2 million rows. From my past reading `Using temporary and Using filesort` are bad for performance. How can i fine tune this query?

---

Here is the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_data_mkt` (
  `ACTIVITY_DT` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country_Cd` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AREA_CD` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AREA_DESC` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION_CD` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION_DESC` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MKT_CD` char(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MKT_NAME` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_tier` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SLS_DIST_CHNL_TYPE_CD` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PPlan_Type` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREPAID_IND` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edge_taken_ind` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Desc` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Plan_Tier` varchar(26) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unlimited_to_Others_cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_UP_Cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_Down_Cnt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lines` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NetAdd` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VOL_DE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INVOL_DE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_ATT_Leap` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_Sprint_Nextel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_TMobile_MetroPcs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortIn_OtherCarriers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_ATT_Leap` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_Sprint_Nextel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_TMobile_MetroPcs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PortOut_OtherCarriers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Net_Sales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Eligible_Net_Sales` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Edge_Net_Sales_All` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Basic_To_Smart` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AAL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `New_To_VZ` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trade_In` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unlimited_to_Others` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_Up` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Data_Step_Down` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `MKT_CD` (`MKT_CD`,`ACTIVITY_DT`),
  KEY `REGION_CD` (`REGION_CD`,`ACTIVITY_DT`,`MKT_CD`),
  KEY `AREA_CD` (`AREA_CD`,`ACTIVITY_DT`),
  KEY `Country_Cd` (`Country_Cd`,`ACTIVITY_DT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: what is your create table so i can match it. run `show create table sales_data_mkt ` and publish

Comment: @Drew added the create statement

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a subquery, does this version help?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(GA) AS TotalGA,
    sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd,
    sales_data_mkt.mkt_name 
  FROM
    sales_data_mkt 
  WHERE sales_data_mkt.country_cd = 'USA' 
    AND activity_dt BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' 
    AND sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY sales_data_mkt.mkt_cd 
  HAVING TotalGA > 0 
  ORDER BY TotalGA DESC
  LIMIT 10 
  ;
```

It probably works even without renaming `GA` to `TotalGA`, that just looks wrong and potentially problematic to me.

Sidenote: If activity_dt is a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, that BETWEEN may not work exactly how you expect.

Comment: this query makes no difference. The explain statement and the runtime are the same. (activity_dt is DATE)

Answer (score 0):

**Lesson #1 in building a "composite" index:**  Put the `= constant` columns first, *then* have *one* 'range' column.

```
  WHERE country_cd = 'USA' 
    AND activity_dt BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31' 
    AND mkt_cd IS NOT NULL
```

So, that needs either of these:

```
INDEX(country_cd, mkt_cd, activity_dt)
INDEX(mkt_cd, country_cd, activity_dt)
```

It said `Using index` indicating that the query was done entirely in the index.

```
key_len: 12 ref: const
```

Needs some decoding.  It says **`const`**, not `const,const`, so it is using only 1 field.  It is using `activity_dt` for the range check (without including it in the `12`, but it has to stumble over the wrong values for `mkt_cd`, making it slower.

The `12` comes from **`Country_Cd varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL`**.  But how, you ask?  The `key_len` is the max, so 3 chars.  since it is `VAR`, a 2-byte length is needed.  And another byte for `NULL`.  Each char is 3 bytes because of `utf8`.  So, 3*3+2+1 = 12 bytes.

- Tip: Say `NOT NULL` if the column will always have a value.
- Tip: Explicitly say `CHARACTER SET ascii` on columns that are always ascii, such as "country code".
- Tip: Since country codes are standardized at 3 letters, then `VAR` is unnecessary.  (I assume you are using the 3-letter standard, not the 2-letter one.)

Follow the tips and `key_len` will drop from 12 to 1*3+0+0 = 3 bytes.

- Tip: Using a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` lets the optimizer give you whatever rows it feels like.  That's ok for simply seeing a few rows, but it is dangerously unpredictable for Production.  (No, the optimizer is free to ignore the inside `ORDER BY`.)
- Tip: By using `HAVING`, you don't need a subquery (as Uueerdo said):

  `SELECT  SUM(GA) AS GA, mkt_cd, mkt_name
      FROM  sales_data_mkt
      WHERE  country_cd = 'USA'
        AND  activity_dt BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31'
        AND  mkt_cd IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY  mkt_cd
      HAVING  SUM(GA) > 0
      ORDER BY  SUM(GA) DESC
      LIMIT  10 ;`
- Tip: InnoDB really needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  If you don't have a combination of columns that is `UNIQUE`, then add an `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- Tip: To avoid computing end-of-month, leap years, and missing whole days, change `activity_dt BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31'` to

  `activity_dt >= '2015-08-01' AND`
  `activity_dt <  '2015-08-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

That will work correctly for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, even the new microsecond-precision datatypes.